# Powerpoint 2013 - How to replace "bullet, blank" by "bullet" in a whole presentation

Tags: vba, powerpoint-2013

it's all in the title ...
I often retrieve .ppt presentations with poorly written slides and want to automate their reformatting.
Ex: replace "* xxx" by "*xxx"
I can't find how to delete a blank (or several) right after a bullet.
Thanks for the support.

Comment: How are you trying to achieve it? Do you have any example of your efforts?

Comment: Hi David, indeed I tried a number of things but went nowhere. Hence I ma stuck, and no have example to show.